# magento add a block to a layout

Tags: php, magento

Im working on a magento project and have come across an issue which i hope that i could have assistance with. I need to integrate a vat verification block . This feature is enabled on the user account creation page and the phtml file simply calls it like follows:-

```
$_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('euvat/widget_taxvat');
echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
```

I would like to include the same in the onepage checkout page (in the billing tab), but if i use the above code i get a blank page, could i know why this issue is and also a possible solution.

Warm Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `var_dump($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())`. I think this call is not possible on the checkout page. Try something like this:

```
$_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('euvat/widget_taxvat');
echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxvat())->toHtml()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i tried that but its not working, the issue is that if i do a var_dump on $_taxvat the page doesnt display, im not sure why

Comment: Do an `exit();` directly after your var_dump. If this does not work, try to var_dump only `$this->getFormData()` or only `$this`.
What happens if you try my two lines of code on the checkout page?

Comment: I get a blank page when i try those two lines, a var_dump on $this also results in the same